# Chart.js br chart only displaying first value

Tags: html, chart.js

I have created a web page in a html file. 
I have used the chart.js plugin to display a bar chart. 
However, only the first value of the array displays in the chart. 
Here is my index.html.

```
         <!DOCTYPE HTML>

        <html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello</title>
    <script src="/Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 

<body>

      <h1>Battery Levels</h1>
    <div>
        <canvas id="myChart1" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script>
        var batlevels = {
            datasets: [{
                data: [20, 40, 10, 30, 50],
                backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#63FF84",
                "#84FF63",
                "#8463FF",
                "#6384FF"
                ]
            }]
        };

        // Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
        var chart1 = document.getElementById("myChart1").getContext("2d");
        new Chart(chart1, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: batlevels
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `data` element includes the `labels` definition.

```js
var batlevels = {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
    datasets: [{        
        label: 'My Dataset',
        data: [20, 40, 10, 30, 50],
        backgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#63FF84', '#84FF63', '#8463FF', '#6384FF']
    }]
};
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart1"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: batlevels,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart1" height="80"></canvas>
```